# Overloading paintComponent()

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I'm currently making a basic connect four game with a GUI and I'm trying to figure out how I can place the pieces on the board. I have a method that can locate which space the user would like to put the piece on, but I'm unsure how to paint the pieces in. Since `paintComponent()` is always called without an actual method call and the default constructor only takes a Graphics object, how could I overload `paintComponent()` so that it can take different arguments (these arguments are the location of the piece) and the compiler will know to call my new `paintComponent()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how could I overload `paintComponent()` so that it can take different arguments

You can't. Or rather, you can create an overloaded method, but the JRE won't call it.

Instead, the code needs to keep a model of the game state, when it changes, call `repaint()`.  In the normal `paintComponent(Graphics)` method, use the model to determine how it should be drawn.

Obviously, for this to work, the model must be within the scope of the method - so you might make it a class attribute.